# Event Sourcing. Aggregates with Children lists or with ParentID?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Should I store in Aggregate lists of children or only ParentID?

Lists of children can be huge (thousands). Adding or removing one child would mean saving back to storage  thousands and thousands children when only one added or removed.
ParentID is very easy to manage. It makes all aggregates simple (no lists!). It allows to quickly create lists by simply querying aggregates by their ParentID. It allows arbitrary level of hierarchies that can be quickly rebuilt recursively without creating huge aggregates. 
If I'd go with ParentID, should I add to events table the field ParentIdGuid to refer to the parent of the aggregate so i can quickly generate lists?

EDIT:

Brad's answer made me realize that parentid will not be included in the resulting json of the child objects that were updated, since I would only include the fields that had changed. Therefore I cannot rely on json indexing of postgress. That means i would have to create a parentid column on the events table itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parent ID on the child is definitely the way to go.  Think of a database foreign key.  The relationship is held as a parent ID pointer in the child record.

When you instantiate your AR in memory to use it, you should populate the list of children using the ParentID pointer.  If this is expensive, which it sounds like it is, maybe you implement a populate-on-demand function so you don't pay the price unless it's necessary.

There are 2 approaches to the Events table.  It either contains all properties of the entity after the change is made, or it can contain just the modified fields.  If you’re in the camp of saving all properties, then the ParentID should be in each event.  If you prefer to save just the changes, then somewhere in the event list for that entity should be the ParentID; possibly just in the creation event.  With Event Sourcing you add up all the change events to arrive at the current state, so this would give you the ParentID in the entity.

Comment: Thx, you made me think about the case of making the change to existing child object. And since I'm in the camp of only recording updated fields, it became apparent to me that parentid will not be included in the resulting json, therefore I cannot rely on json indexing of postgress. That means i would have to create a parentid column on the events table itself.